# Add NPM profile to places to pull projects from for careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

It would be great to be able to pull projects from your [Node Packaged Modules (NPM)](https://npmjs.org/) profile as well.  I've authored several open source tools as part of my employment, so they're stored under my employer's GitHub account, but published to NPM under my account.

Comment: For those not familiar with NPM, care to explain what it is?

Comment: A note for the suggested duplicate - the question is not a duplicate but the answer on that post also mentions NPM.